# Need help installing Colorbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Colorbox with Drupal 8 (within a VM) but the images are not showing up in an overlay. I have followed the instructions and installed the module and the colorbox javascript library into the libraries folder.

In Drupal's status report screen, it says that the colorbox library is installed.

When I examine the page with the images I would like to display, I can see that none of the Colorbox libraries are loaded. I suspect that I need to add a entry in MYTHEME.libraries.yml to load the Colorbox Javascript. Can someone show me what that entry would look like (if indeed I need that to get Colorbox working).

If that is not the issue, then what am I missing?

I noticed that if I use drush to install the Colorbox-plugin it works. But once I reboot the VM, it doesn't work anymore. So this would indicate to me that some setting is being lost, which leads me to think its the libraries.yml file that needs to be updated.

**NOTE**

I should add that this is a custom theme that I am developing. My theme is not using any custom JavaScript files, so that should not be the issue. I tested colorbox with the default Bartik theme and it works. I have no idea why when my theme is selected that the colorbox javascipt files are not loaded into the page.

Comment: `I suspect that I need to add a entry in MYTHEME.libraries.yml to load the Colorbox Javascript.` No, according to the [install docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1971564), there is no need to do that.

Comment: What version of the colorbox module are you using and what version is the library that you using? I've used Colorbox op D8 websites and there is no need to alter your theme.

Comment: Did you install the [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes the libraries module is installed and it still has this problem.

Comment: @FonsVandamme I am using colorbox module 8.1.2 and the colorbox 1.x library.